# How to remove an element from an array after it's called only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, splice

When a random element is called from the `videos` array, it should be deleted without the index being empty and undefined afterwards. The problem is that `splice_video();` keeps calling the same element twice, when it's supposed to delete the element from the array after being called only once. (Each element in the array is a function).

```
        function playNextVideo() {
            const videos = [showVideo1,showVideo2,showVideo3,showVideo4,showVideo5];
            const random_video = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
            const video = videos.splice(random_video, 1);
            const splice_video = video[0]();
            splice_video();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the array of functions outside, not inside, so that the removal of the function from the array is persistent.

```
const videoFns = [showVideo1, showVideo2, showVideo3, showVideo4, showVideo5];
function playNextVideo() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoFns.length);
    const [videoFn] = videoFns.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    videoFn();
}
```

Live demo:

```js
const videoFns = Array.from(
  { length: 5 },
  (_, i) => () => console.log('video ' + i)
);
function playNextVideo() {
    if (!videoFns.length) return;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoFns.length);
    const [videoFn] = videoFns.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    videoFn();
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', playNextVideo);
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried this. It doesn't play the next video when ``const videos = [];`` is outside the function.

Comment: Is it because of ``document.getElementById('video4').addEventListener('ended',playNextVideo,false);`` ?

Comment: @ChrisLuhrsVA See live demo in answer. The code appears to work just fine.

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was that all this code was in the HTML file and not in my videos.js file. I feel so dumb lol I'll mark your answer as accepted now.